# How to forward traffic out to the internet from Ethernet through WiFi while interfaces on a different subnet?

Tags: mac, network, internet-sharing

On my MacBook I am connected to internet through WiFi but I also have a router for my lab connected to Ethernet port.

```
wifi(en1): 192.168.0.4/24 with 192.168.0.1 gateway.  
ethernet(en0): 192.168.1.254/30 with no gateway.
```

When I try `ping 192.168.1.254` or even `ping 192.168.1.253` which is the other end of my Ethernet I do get a reply but when I run `ping -S 192.168.1.254 192.168.0.4` or `ping -S 192.168.1.254 192.168.0.1` ping an address on the internet I get this:

```
~ ping -S 192.168.1.254 192.168.0.4

PING 192.168.0.4 (192.168.0.4) from 192.168.1.254: 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

So while WiFi can ping Ethernet and further to it, Ethernet cannot ping WiFi or my ISP's router or go out to the internet.

My question is how I can make Ethernet reach my ISP's router and therefore internet as well as other devices on my WiFi network.

I tried static routes but it is not working. I was only able to ping WiFi (192.168.0.4) by sharing my WiFi connection to Ethernet from preferences, and then assigning  the IP address of eth to the bridge that was created with the following command `sudo ifconfig bridge100 inet 192.168.1.254/30` but still I could not ping 192.168.0.1 or any other device on the WiFi network.